# Помогите решить задачу с перебором классов и добавлением нового

Tags: javascript

Есть множество div элементов с одинаковым классом.При переборе я должен найти тот div в блоке которого указано например буква 'h'
и присвоить ему новый класс.

```
  <input type="text" id="inp">
  <div class="buttoN"> m</div>
  <div class="buttoN">p</div>
  <div class="buttoN">h</div>
  <div class="buttoN">i</div>
  <div class="buttoN">b</div>

.buthover{
  color: red;
}

let inp = document.querySelector("#inp");
let but = document.querySelectorAll('.buttoN');
inp.onkeydown = function () {

.................
    for (i = 0; i < but.length; i++) {

............................


    }
}
```

Ссылка https://codepen.io/fortune82/pen/xBMKKz?editors=1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let inp = document.querySelector("#inp");
let but = document.querySelectorAll('.buttoN');
inp.onkeydown = function(e) {
  for(var i = 0; i < but.length; i++) {
    if (but[i].textContent == e.key)
      but[i].classList.add("red");
  }
}
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp">
<div class="buttoN">m</div>
<div class="buttoN">p</div>
<div class="buttoN">h</div>
<div class="buttoN">i</div>
<div class="buttoN">b</div>
```